# Bulk csv to shapefile (using ogr2ogr)

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, ogr2ogr

Is bulk conversion from csv to shapefile possible with ogr2ogr? I can do it file by file when I first create dbf file, then using vrt file I create shapefile. But using command

`for /R %f in (*.csv) do ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f "ESRI Shapefile" "%~dpnf.shp" "%f`

I am able to get only the dbf and prj file, but not qpj, shp nor shx files. I have hundreds of csv files in one folder I would like to convert to shapefiles, but I'm on half way to achieve this.

**Edit**
For a single file I first created .dbf file: `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" all8.dbf all8.csv`

Then, I created all8.vrt file:

`<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTLayer name="all8">
    <SrcDataSource>all8.csv</SrcDataSource>
    <SrcLayer>all8</SrcLayer>
    <GeometryType>wkbPoint</GeometryType>
    <LayerSRS>WGS84</LayerSRS>
    <GeometryField encoding="PointFromColumns" x="Longitude" y="Latitude"/>
  </OGRVRTLayer>
</OGRVRTDataSource>`

And finally run: `ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" all8 all8.vrt`

I also tried to replace "all8" in .vrt file with "*" (to create multiple shapefiles using only one .vrt file), but that did'nt work.

Comment: .qpj files are only created by qgis, not ogr2ogr. Please include your workflow for creating a single shape file. It seems you don't get the geometry information right at the moment.

Comment: You are right about the .qpj file. Thank you for pointing this out. Added single shapefile creation process to my first post.

Comment: Do all your CSV files have similar structure? Could you add one line into your question? Have you read http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html and how to use X_POSSIBLE_NAMES and Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES open options?

Comment: I don't see any reference to a vrt file in your batch command line.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A modern-enough GDAL can convert CSV files directly into shapefiles. For the `test.csv` file in the documentation, http://www.gdal.org/drv_csv.html - you can do:

```
ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lon* -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lat*  -f "ESRI Shapefile" test.shp test.csv
```

to create `test.shp` (and `.dbf` et al) from `test.csv`, converting from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3857 as it goes.

You seem to be using Windows command syntax to loop over your files, which I dont know, but all you need to change is the destination and source names for each shapefile.

In a unix shell the relevant loop syntax is:

```
for f in *.csv ; do echo $f ${f%csv}shp ; done
```

(replace `echo` with your command, and put `"$f"` and `"${f%csv}shp"` where you want the csv and shapefile in the command)

Comment: @user30184 Thank you for the link! @Spacedman Thanks to his comments I was able to find a command 
 that works on my Windows: `for /R %f in (*.csv) do ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -oo X_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lon* -oo Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES=Lat*  -f "ESRI Shapefile" "%~dpnf.shp" %f`