# Convert To/From Esri Mobile Geodatabase and OGC GPKG GeoPackage SQLite databases

Tags: esri-geodatabase, geopackage, mobile-gis

Trying to find a method to convert Esri Mobile Geodatabase to GeoPackage Vector Features database both formats are SQLite database
Esri uses ST_Geometry blob for the geometry and geopackage uses a derivative of WKB.
I don't want to have to use ArcGIS Pro or FME for this was looking for a console/command line tool or Python script.

Comment: Have you tried ogr2ogr?

Comment: GDAL Ogr2OGR does not support esri mobile geodatabase

Comment: Spatialite has some functions that could help

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/geodatabases/manage-mobile-gdb/enable-stgeometry-extension-for-sql.htm?s=03  SELECT load_extension('stgeometry_sqlite.dll','SDE_SQL_funcs_init');  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/a-quick-tour-of-sql-functions-used-with-st-geometry.htm

Comment: Perhaps first creating a CSV file with this database and then using `ogr2ogr` to create a GeoPackage could solve this issue: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419212/173457